# Possibility to write a code to put auto names for controls using different rules in Orbeon Form Builder

Tags: orbeon

We all know that when we create new control in FB it gives its name `control-1`. When we create the next control it give its name `control-2` an so on. Is it possible to write a rule for giving names to controls? For instance: For specific column in grid, column with name A, give to all controls in this column name which starts with `A_` suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a form author, you can change the name of a control after you add it in Form Builder. However, if you want to change the default naming scheme, you would have to change code in Orbeon Forms. Currently, this is done with `controlName(nextId(doc, "control"))` in [`ToolboxOps.scala`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fb/ToolboxOps.scala).